# Need tool to determine if host is suitable for VMWare

Tags: vmware-esx

I have an exchange 2003 server and I need to determine what resources it uses and if my ESX host can support this server

Comment: You need to provide more information.

What are the hardware specifications of the Exchange server, and the ESX server?

How many Exchange users? How much disk space is in use? 

Tom

Comment: It is a 1 user exchange server used for mailbox journaling.  4Exchange servers with a total od 4000 users journal to this server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct mechanism for doing this is to use VMWare's own "[Guided Consolidation](https://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-server/features.html)" approach which is a plug-in for vCenter. It monitors candidate servers for a period of days, noting max/average/min stats for CPU, memory, disk and network usage - coming up with a an overall profile and recommendations for minimum ESX/i host configuration. I couldn't recommend it higher, it was created for situations exactly like yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Exchange 2003 on a ESX virtual machine with Windows Server 2003 or 2008, that should be fine. Give the Guest OS the same CPU/Memory you currently have or the server has as minimum requirements.

What you need to figure out is does the hardware meet ESX requirements or not and you can find that on VMWare site.

Answer (score 1):

What resources does your current Exchange server have, what resources (total and free) do your ESX hosts have?

Exchange will run happily on ESX, we do it with Exchange 2003, but on vmware as with physical hardware, if you starve it of CPU, memory or especially disk, it won't be pleasant.

Do check your host on the ESX compatibility guides.

Answer (score -3):

> Need tool to determine if host is
>   suitable for VMWare

it is called eyes.

> I have an exchange 2003 server and I
>   need to determine what resources it
>   uses and if my ESX host can support
>   this server

You tell me. Does the ESX host have enough IO, CPU and memory to support that server? All that is quite easy to figure out. Look at CPU load, memory and IO, plus the hardware side especially of IO - you will not get a loaded 10 disc exchhane be happy with a large slow vmware store.